# gz file needs a huge amount of disk space to extract

Tags: linux, diskspace, gzip

I downloaded a compressed file in gz format of 4.5 GB with uncompressed file size of 15.7 GB.

When I extracted the file in Ubuntu 14.04 (using the archive manager), I got a message related to insufficient disk space.

However, after inspection I had more than 40 GB available.

Previous attempts to extract this file failed because apparently I didn't have enough disk space, but I was surprised by how much extra disk space I needed to finish the extraction.

I expected that some extra amount of disk space is needed to allow for some temporary files, but so much extra disk space seems a bit excessive.

Is this the expected behavior? The same happened in an EC2 instance with Ubuntu Server 14.04 using gzip -d file.gz.

Comment: Is the disk with 40GB space and the disk on which you are uncompressing same ?

Comment: Yes, the 40GB are contained in a 250GB partition where I was uncompressing the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *may* be that it creates a temporary file to hold the output, copies that file to the eventual destination, then deletes the temporary. It may also be that the temporary copy is stored on another file system, one with less than 15.7G available.

You can probably bypass the use of temporary files by using `zcat`, `gzcat`, `gunzip -c` or `gunzip --to-stdout` and then redirecting the output to a file directly.

Comment: I'm not sure if it tried to store in another file system. I think that is not likely my case. However, maybe if it created a temporary copy of 15.7 plus the final stored file, that might be near the disk space I had available. In any case, those are nice commands. Are there drawbacks of using gunzip -c or zcat instead of the default command?

Comment: @Robert, the place where temporary files go may not be under your control, it may use `/tmp`, `$TEMP`, `$TMPDIR`, or some other means of finding a temporary area. In terms of possible disadvantages, only that the uncompressed file is sent to standard output by default. Unless you want fifteen billion characters hitting your console, you'll need to ensure you redirect it somewhere :-) Such as `zcat myfile.gz >myfile`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **ARCHIVE MANAGER**, I suggest you to use the command prompt to uncompress the file.

> **$ tar xvf file name**

Comment: Are you sure this works for a gz file? Usually, I use tar -zxvf file.tar.gz but I think that command requires tar.gz files

Comment: It only works for `.tgz` or `.tar.gz` gzipped tar archive files. And `gunzip` is then invoked underneath.